# Using MS Access with a Universal App

Tags: ms-access, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am writing a Windows Universal App (using vb.net).
How can I access a Microsoft Access Database to retrieve some data?

Is it quite possible? I do not find anything with Google :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect to MS Access using OLE DB provider. Unfortunately this is not included in the .NET Core which is used by UWP. AFAIK this is not possible at this time.